# C# ASP.Net Webforms - string - static vs static readonly

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have hit a bit of confusion in regards to using these varibles within an ASP.Net application.

`public static string Complete = "Complete";`

As far i'm aware, this value will be global for all users, but the value is not guaranteed to exist due to the application pool recycling and the value is not assigned on recycle?

`public static readonly string Complete = "Complete";`

Does the `readonly` flag mean that the value is always available due to getting initialized with the static constructor of the class, meaning that the value will always be available?

As far as I'm aware, the following would happen in the `readonly` scenario:

1. Access Variable

   - Is class constructed? No? Assign variable
2. Application Restarts
3. Go to 1

Is there any difference between the `readonly` and non-readonly version? I suppose we could also write it as follows to guarantee the variable:

`public static string Complete { get { return "Complete"; } }`

Comment: Or simply write `public const string Complete = "Complete";` ;-)

Comment: I was going to include `const` but, don't all referencing assemblies need updating if using said `const`?

Comment: @MiG exactly, which is a very powerful reason not to use const lightly; always prefer readonly over const when you can.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`readonly` will simply stop the value held by the variable being changed once initialized.  It doesn't affect the life time of the static - it is still the same as before.

Note that if the static is a reference, the `readonly` attribute doesn't stop the underlying object from being mutated, it only stops the value of the static variable from being changed - in the case of a class reference, that value is the reference itself.

MSDN C# docs on readonly:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7(v=VS.100).aspx

A `readonly` static will have a similar affect to a `const` (assuming the thing you are making static is elligible for `const`) when you talk about having a global unchanging value.  When you first attempt to access the static, it will be initialized on the spot and never be allowed to change.

So:

```
public static readonly string Something = "what";
```

Will in effect behave like:

```
public const string Something = "what";
```

Although the latter is compile time constant, and the former isn't - so it's behaviour has some key differences.  I was more talking about the idea of a value available globally that doesn't change.

In terms of ASP.NET and recycling of statics, the difference between the readonly static and const is that the static simply incurs the charge of initializing if it hasn't been initialized yet.  However for the usage being described, `const` is a better fit.

Comment: So in an ASP.Net application, both variables will always return their expected value or not due to application pool recycling?

Comment: @MiG if a readonly static is recycled, so long as the value isn't some crazy runtime determined thing, then `static readonly` and `const` will achieve the same for you.  This is because the static will be initialized on first access.  If the value is basic, go for `const`.

Comment: Right, i'm with it now. Whereas the non `readonly` won't be initialized on first access?

Comment: @MiG a normal static can be initialized at any point, because it is writable.  A `readonly` variable forces initialization inline or in a constructor and cannot be changed afterwards.  If you have `static string Foo = null`, then on first use you get null, but you can later set into it.  The `readonly` modifier doesn't change how statics are handled, it simply forces initialization of the value at key points and stops it from being written to at any other point.

Comment: OK, ignoring that it can be assigned at any point, say I put `static string Foo = "Foo"`, is it guaranteed to always be Foo?

Comment: @MiG Yes, even when recycled.  When you access it, if it hasn't been initialized, it will be at that point.  If the value you put in it will always be the same, then you will always get the same value out regardless of lifecycle.  The point there is then, `static` is pointless over `const` unless the type you want global cannot be made `const`.

Answer (score 0):

> public static string Complete = "Complete";

is guaranteed. But it also can be modified. Use *const* if you want it to be a constant.

More info abot const vs readyonly vs static readonly [Here](http://abdullin.com/journal/2008/10/22/const-vs-readonly-vs-static-readonly-in-c-net.html)

Answer (score 0):

The `readonly` keyword tells the compiler that this class variable can only be initialized along with its declaration or in its c'tor (because it is a static field, the two options are equivalent anyway).

Apart from that, there's no other difference.

HTH - Thomas